# How to replace home link anchor text with image

Tags: navigation, breadcrumb

I'm trying to replace home link text with an image for breadcrumb trailer. Mouse cursor is still pointer but image doesn't appear. I'm using [this breadcrumb trailer](https://github.com/justintadlock/breadcrumb-trail/blob/master/inc/breadcrumbs.php)

How could I this working please [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atahta/vu3dgzaj/3/)

```
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="" class="trail-item trail-begin">
<a href="#" rel="home" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a>
<meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
</li>
```

CSS:

```
li.trail-begin {
    display: inline-block;
     font-size: 0;
     color: 000;
    height: 25px;
    position: static;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
}
li.trail-begin a  {
    background-image: url("https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-T3iC1fWjXIM/XqVHr8gv4GI/AAAAAAAAAGE/k5EviLmoDwkttKB9sUgjVbCSTlinrOqlACLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/1-2-home-png-image-thumb.png");
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is much more like a CSS question.
The anchor a by default is display as inline. So it doesn't have height and width unless text, image etc inside with finite dimension. To make it work, just add `display:block;` to the css so it expands to match the parent container.

```
li.trail-begin {
    display: inline-block;
     font-size: 0;
     color: 000;
    height: 25px;
    position: static;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
}
li.trail-begin a  {
    background-image: url("https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-T3iC1fWjXIM/XqVHr8gv4GI/AAAAAAAAAGE/k5EviLmoDwkttKB9sUgjVbCSTlinrOqlACLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/1-2-home-png-image-thumb.png");
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 25px;
    display: block; /* <-------- */
}
```